# DIV next to centered div

Tags: html, css, css-float, positioning

[image]

```
body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
}

#wrapper {

}

#login {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;

    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}


#registercontainer {
    position: relative;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 1050px;
}

#register {
    position: absolute;
    left: 740px;
    top: 50px;
}
```

//

```
    <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="login">
            <h2>Login to The Something Project</h2>
            <form action="game" method="post">
                <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" placeholder="username"><br>
                <input type="text" name="usericon" placeholder="http://imgur.com/icon.png"><br>
                <br>
                <input type="submit" value="login">
            </form>
        </div>


        <div id="registercontainer">
            <div id="register">
                <h2>Register for The Something Project</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I want to have a div next to the centered div (see the image above) but what i get instead is this. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3hz3Q.png

How do i solve this?

Greetings

Comment: Can your wrapper div be a fixed size or does it have to be flexible?

Comment: I think you could just float your log-in div and your register div left then and give the login div the appropriate margin-left to place it in the center.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I imagine there are quite a few approaches you can take. Here is one.

Using the same HTML structure as in your example, the goal can be achieved thus:

- Make all elements except the main wrapper `inline-block`.
- Center the "centered" element by giving `text-align: center` to the main wrapper.
- Put the sidebar out of the document flow by giving it `position: absolute`. This requires that you give its container `position: relative` as well.
- Give the sidebar's container zero width and height so that it doesn't affect the centering calculations. Give it `vertical-align: top` so that its top edge (which is also the sidebar's top edge) aligns with the top edge of the centered element.
- Optionally specify `text-align` for the centered element and the sidebar if you don't want their contents to be centered within themselves.

As a bonus, with this approach you can directly specify the widths for both the centered div and the sidebar in just one place.

[**See it in action**](http://jsfiddle.net/GJpuQ/).

Comment: You are worth all those 10 golden badges, 69 silver badges and 125 bronze badges. You, my sir, are smart.

Comment: This solution works, nice job.  I'd be interested to how to have the sidebar to the left, though.

Answer (score 2):

Please, check the repaired **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fedosov/Z4Tmk/)** of your markup.

You need to remove `#registercontainer` and place `#register` into `#login` plus some position modifications according to centered block width.

[image: Result]

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="login">
        <h2>Login to The Something Project</h2>
        <form action="game" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="username" maxlength="20" placeholder="username"><br>
            <input type="text" name="usericon" placeholder="http://imgur.com/icon.png"><br>
            <br>
            <input type="submit" value="login">
        </form>
        <div id="register">
            <h2>Register for The Something Project</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>​
```

And CSS:

```
body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
}

#login {
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}

#register {
    position: absolute;
    left: 420px;
    top: 20px;
    width: 100px;
}​
```

Comment: As someone who is a maximum noob at CSS I found this answer much easier to understand and implement on my own.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/nUk77/
Or even closer to your original code: http://jsfiddle.net/rSbzT/

Instead of absolute positioning the register div I positioned its container.
The absolute positioning makes it break from the html flow so it doesn't interfere with the margin-right:auto;

Answer (score 0):

`float: right` should solve your problem. remember to add an empty div-container with `float:clear` afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things going on here - first, your width on the "registercontainer" div is 1050 - which will force it to clear, causing the "register" div to appear below the 'centered' div.

I would go about this a different way. *If you are dealing with a fixed-width site:* I would float #login and #registercontainer next to each other, and give #wrapper an explicit width. Then, set #wrapper to have a margin left using a % that would approximate the placement that you're after.

See this [JS Fiddle for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/chippper/UbqpJ/). Here is the CSS (I changed the background colors for clarity):

```
body {
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    font-family: sans-serif;
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #e0e0e0;
    width: 960px;
}

#wrapper {
   width: 760px;
    background: blue;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin-left: 35%;
}

#login {
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
    width: 360px;
    padding: 20px;


    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
    border-radius: 15px;
}


#registercontainer {
    float:left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    clear: none;
    width: 350px;
    background: red;
}

#register {

}​
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    <div style="position: relative; display: inline-block; padding: 0 30px;">
    <h2>CENTERED ELEMENT</h2>
        <div style="position: absolute; top: 0; left: 100%;">
            ELEMENT NEXT TO CENTERED DIV
    </div>
```

Use 100% in position absolute.
And use padding for the centered element to push the side div further.